# why doesn't mkdir -p /tmp/one/two/tree print anything when directories exist?

Tags: linux

When I run `mkdir -p` on an existing directory, that doesn't print anything,

```
strace -e mkdir,write mkdir -p /tmp/one/two/tree
mkdir("/tmp", 0777)                     = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdir("one", 0777)                      = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdir("two", 0777)                      = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdir("tree", 0777)                     = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

But when I run `mkdir` without `-p` option, it informs me that the directory exists.

```
strace -e mkdir,write mkdir  /tmp/one/two/tree
mkdir("/tmp/one/two/tree", 0777)        = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
write(2, "mkdir: ", 7mkdir: )                  = 7
write(2, "cannot create directory \342\200\230/tmp/"..., 47cannot create directory ‘/tmp/one/two/tree’) = 47
write(2, ": File exists", 13: File exists)           = 13
write(2, "\n", 1
)        

           = 1
```

Comment: It took me a solid five minutes to realize your English is bad enough that you meant "doesn't print anything". I was deeply confused, because... I mean, clearly, it was printing nothing. Anyway, suggesting edit now.

Comment: @ParthianShot Thanks, I know my english is bad, but i don't need that kind of comment, many people in this site are not english people.

Comment: Well, normally I wouldn't, but that wasn't the only huge issue with the question.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's what the flag is suposed to do; this from `man mkdir` (from GNU coreutils 8.21):

> ```
>    -p, --parents
>           no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
> ```

Comment: there is a way to tell to mkdir to print the error if the directories exsist?

Comment: Yes; don't use `-p`.  Using a flag that's explicitly supposed to prevent logging, and then asking how to make it log, is not terribly wise.

Comment: but I don't use -p flag the mkdir print an error only for the last directory, I would likt to print an error for the 3 directories.

Comment: So write a script that does what you want.  `mkdir -p` doesn't do what you want, so that isn't a good thing to use.  I might add, though, that a `mkdir` command that logs errors when *any* of the parents exist is going to be a noisy beast: `/` *always* exists, so it's going to grumble about that every single time you use it.

Comment: @MadHatter: +1, but in all fairness, `/` would be a fairly easy thing to exclude for such a warning :)

Comment: @Sven As we can see from his output, `/` is always assumed to exist by `mkdir`.